# "Error:(18, 9) error: illegal start of expression " In AndroidSudio 1.1.0

Tags: android

I'm learning android app development using AndroidStudio on Windows by following the tutorials on developer.android.com site and I'm stuck on passing the Intebt to my second activity.
It gives me following error:Error:(18, 9) error: illegal start of expression

Here's my code snippet

```
package com.akshay.calc;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.akshay.calc.MESSAGE";
}

@Override
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Thanx!

Comment: try making EXTRA_MESSAGE a member of MainActivity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be declaring your class variables outside that first method:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.akshay.calc.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

//Etc.
```

Comment: Yeah ! Thanx Problem Solved . Just a query now What does that "@Override" really mean?

Comment: Glad that was it! Thanks for the rep! The @Override there as a JavaDoc tag. It's so others (or even you perhaps!) can easily see what methods do, what arguments they have, and as you asked, when it overrides another method using Javadoc. Have a look at this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#tag and this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Answer (score 0):

move

```
 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.akshay.calc.MESSAGE";
```

in the class scope. In java public and static are not allowed in the scope of a method

Answer (score 0):

Declare it before the oncreate  method

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.akshay.calc.MESSAGE";

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the problem is with

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.akshay.calc.MESSAGE";
```

being inside your `onCreate` method. Not only are public and static not allowed in a method, even if they were `EXTRA_MESSAGE` would only have scope within `onCreate` and not be available to your `sendMessage` method.

Additionally, I would define this in your strings.xml, since you will also need that same key string to get the data back out in your new `Activity`. By defining it in the `Activity` you would need to change it twice if you ever updated it. By putting it in strings.xml you can call it from anywhere in your app and only have one place to update.